# "i am awake" Could it also mean "I just woke up"

Tags: word-meaning

I know " I am awake" means "I am alert"/"I am not sleeping" but could it also mean "i just woke up"?

I was awake means "I was alert"/"I was not sleeping" but could it also mean "I was woken up"?

Answer (score 1):

"Awake" simply means the state of not being asleep. "I am awake" makes no implications about how long you have been awake. You may have woken up, or *been* woken up, just a moment ago or hours ago.

As usual, context will do more than the actual words to make the meaning clear.

Comment: thanks so are my both interpretations right in my question?

Comment: If someone came into your bedroom on tiptoe trying not to wake you, but did anyway, you might say "It's all right - I'm awake." You might also say "I was awake before dawn", meaning that you woke up then.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Can i also say such this in future."If you go in his room, He will be awake" (as in he will be conscious,alert/not sleeping) and (the other meaning that will wake up)

Comment: No. _He will be awake_ would be a prediction that he will already be awake, not that he will wake up at that point.

Comment: @Kate Bunting cheers.my last query.So two interpretations for "awake" could only be in "I am awake/I was awake. Did i understand that correct?

Comment: _Awake_ just means _not asleep_. In some contexts, it can be used in the sense 'having just woken up'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Can " I am asleep/ I was asleep" can also be used in the sense of "Having just slept"(although the main sense is "I am sleeping/I was sleeping)

Comment: Well, no-one is likely to say "I am asleep" for obvious reasons! You might say "I was asleep until a moment ago" or "...until you woke me".

Comment: @BilalZafar Comments are not meant for extended discussion. If your question needs to be updated, please use the "edit" button on the question itself to add details (for instance, in some of these comments you suggest a situation. The context of the situation would matter more to the meaning than the words you use.) Or, if you need to know something that's different than your original question, please open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

No, **I am awake** does most certainly not mean: I've just woken up.

I just woke up. is colloquial.
I've just woken up. is more standard phrasing.

I **was woken up**. means someone or something **woke you up**.

It does not mean: I was awake (not sleeping) when [something happened].

**to be awake** = to not be sleeping
**to be woken up** = to have one's sleep interrupted by something; to cause the sleeping to end.

Comment: but i often heard "I am just awake" "I am awake yet" describing "having woken up". What do you reckon?

Comment: "I am just awake" is not idiomatic for this. "I am awake yet" is completely unidiomatic.

Comment: how about "I am not awake yet" is this unidiomatic too?

Comment: @BilalZafar It's idiomatic but impossible **really**. Because if you say that, you have to be awake....

Answer (score -2):

> "i am awake" Could it also mean "I just woke up"

No. "I am awake", just means that you are awake, not **just** waking up.

> I was awake means "I was alert"/"I was not sleeping" but could it also mean "I was woken up"?

No also. "I was awake" also cannot mean you were woken up, as "I was woken up" means **someone** woke you up

Comment: Frost thanks but I am refering to "I am awake" and "I was awake", not "I am sleeping/I was sleeping"

Comment: but if i say "I am just awake/I am awake yet, then woul not it mean i just woke up?

Comment: "I am just awake/I am awake yet" are both grammatically wrong so you cannot use them

Comment: Kindly check the remarks of Kate Bunting and Andy Bonner

Comment: You interpretation is right if you say "I am awake" or "I was awake" " meaning that "you are awake"/"you were awake",(State of not being asleep) but as Kate Bunting told sometimes "I am awake" and "I was awake" might mean "having just woken up" specially if you add "just/yet" as in "I am just awake/ i am awake yet"